# Python MySQLdb - Export query to csv without line terminators

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

So basically im using MySQLdb query dialy images of my tables and i want to save them in .csv but one of the fields has line terminators (\n) and i cant figure out how to get rid of them so my csv doesnt break.

Here is the python im using:

```
results = cur.execute(sql)
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="",
                    user="",
                    passwd="",
                    db="" )
cur = db.cursor()
sql = """" big query here """
results = cur.execute(sql)
with open("out.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
    csv_writer.writerow(cur)
```

Is there a easy way to replace \n chars for just spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

import csv
import sys

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n')

Or:

with open("out.csv","wb",newline='') as csv_file:

Comment: open does not support newline in python2 and im forced to use python2 since MySQLdb is not supported in python3. Using io.open is not an option since im dealing with str and wb flag doesnt allow newline neigther.

Comment: I read his question to mean that one of the columns has a newline character in its text.

Answer (score 0):

If the newline is in appearing in the text of your column  maybe something like this wouldwork.

```
csv_writer.writerow([i[0].replace('\n',' ') for i in cur.description])
```